# steamcommunity does not return error code

Tags: node.js, steam, steam-web-api, steambot

I'm using node-steamcommunity to get user's inventory 
The module responded "[Error: malformed response]"
After doing some debugging I've managed to see the raw response from steamcommunity server (request to: https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/STEAM_ID/inventory/json/570/1/):
The response is

```
{"success": false}
```

The problem is that the normal response should contain the error like this:

```
{"success": false, "Error": "The profile is private"}
```

So now I can neither get the user's inventory nor the reason why I can't do this.
Could some one point me to the right way of getting the user's inventory from steam

**Update:**

after doing some investigation I've found something interesting:

1. When I login as a normal user, i get a sessionid.
2. With that key I can access to profile inventory
3. When I start bot I get also get sessionId but when I'm trying to request with bot's session id I get the { success: false} response without any explanation.

Does anyone has an idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 is not a correct contextid for Dota 2 (570).

You're looking for https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/STEAM_ID/inventory/json/570/2/ (notice the 2 at the end instead of 1).

Answer (score 0):

You tried accepting trade? If yes then maybe need use:

```
let key = SteamTotp.getConfirmationKey(identity_secret, time, 'allow');
```

key is argument for response function

Comment: No, i did not try to accept the trade yet, I just want to see if my friends items list, after thatI will make a decision to make the trade or not